# How to properly close out of Inno Setup wizard without prompt?

Tags: inno-setup, suppress

Part of my installer checks for a latest version on our server and downloads automatically if necessary, just after the welcome page. The actual check and download are in a function `CheckForNewInstaller` which returns `True` if new installer was downloaded and has executed, and `False` if it needs to continue. If the new installer was downloaded (`True`) then the wizard needs to shut down.

Using the following code, I have done this using `WizardForm.Close`. However, it still prompts the user if they're sure they wish to cancel. In normal scenarios, I still want the user to get this prompt if they attempt to close the installer. However, I need to suppress this dialog when I need to forcefully close the wizard. I also cannot be terminating the process, because the cleanup process wouldn't happen properly.

```
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
  X: Integer;
begin
  Log('NextButtonClick(' + IntToStr(CurPageID) + ') called');
  Result := True;
  case CurPageID of
    wpWelcome: begin
      if CheckForNewInstaller then begin
        //Need to close this installer as new one is starting
        WizardForm.Close;
      end;
    end;
    ....
  end;
end;
```

How can I close this installer completely down without any further user interaction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done by handling the `CancelButtonClick` event and setting the `Confirm` parameter...

```
var
  ForceClose: Boolean;

procedure Exterminate;
begin
  ForceClose:= True;
  WizardForm.Close;  
end;

procedure CancelButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer; var Cancel, Confirm: Boolean);
begin
  Confirm:= not ForceClose;
end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
  X: Integer;
begin
  Log('NextButtonClick(' + IntToStr(CurPageID) + ') called');
  Result := True;
  case CurPageID of
    wpWelcome: begin
      if CheckForNewInstaller then begin
        Exterminate;
      end;
    end;
    ....
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Well, then you're using a wrong event. If you want to prevent the installer to even start you should use the `InitializeSetup` event method. In all cases, this answer is a wrong way.

Comment: @TLama This isn't the very first thing, I want this to happen after the welcome page. I never wanted to prevent the wizard from starting, or I would have put it in `InitializeSetup`.

Comment: @TLama Actually since I posted this question/answer, I changed the logic and now there's even a page in the wizard asking if they'd like to check for a new version.

Comment: You've said "at the very first step" and that means before the wizard starts. And I agree with the idea to not even start the setup if there's a newer version. But I see, you've got your own way which you want to offer to your users. Good luck then ;-)

Comment: @TLama Yeah, that statement was very loosely defined :-)